# How to fetch file time which is last created using batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I have one folder which contain another subfolder and that subfolder contains different extensions file.

Now I want using batch script how to extract name and time of that file in a subfolder.

I tried but failed to retrieve time of that file which is located in subfolders.

I want only this code in the batch script only.

Comment: why you have tagged `sql server` ?

Comment: SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p oname=Enter FileName::

for /D %%a in (*) do (
 SET var="%%a"
 echo The ServerName is :: !var! >>%oname% & echo.>>%oname%
  
 for /R /D %%b in ("%%a\*") do (
  SET var1="%%b"
  SET var2="%%~nb"
  
 echo the subfolder of  !var! is:: '' !var2!>>%oname% & echo.>>%oname%
  
  for /f  %%x in ( 'DIR /A-D /B /OD /T:C "%%b\*.bak" ') do ( set bakFile="%%x" set BakTime="%%~tx")
  echo The Latest Bak File Name and Time is !bakFile!>> %oname% !BakTime! >> %oname%
  SET bakFile=""

     )
   )

ENDLOCAL

Comment: Please don't post code in comments! [Edit] your question an put it there -- properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)!

Answer (score 1):

using substitution of variable reference `for /?`, echo can be changed by any other command or call

command-line

```
for %f in (filepath\pattern) do echo "%f : %~tf"
```

in a script the percent sign must be double

```
for %%f in (filepath\pattern) do echo "%%f : %%~tf"
```

---

#### EDIT after comment

here an example of how to use labels to simulate function and to avoid expansion tricks, note that labels are not exactly functions they are executed in normal flow, that's why there's `goto :main` to skip `:process` and `goto :eof` to return.

```
@echo off

goto :main

:process
echo file name is: %~1 and time is %~2
goto :eof


:main
for %%x in (AppData\Local\*.*) do call :process "%%x" "%%~tx"
```

---

but with batch script command set is very limited, also should be noted that date and time output can't be formatted and are dependent of system language settings.

If powershell can be used, it's worth taking the time to learn.
Different file time properties :

```
$file.CreationTime
$file.CreationTimeUtc
$file.LastAccessTime
$file.LastAccessTimeUtc
$file.LastWriteTime
$file.LastWriteTimeUtc
```

Comment: the modifier `~z` returns the size, but you noticed that yourself. I'd add @ to the echo to have a less cluttered output

Comment: @LotPings, thank you for your feedback indeed it's just an example

Comment: @NahuelFouilleulI tried but it fetches the only name of  file from the folder but not created date here is my for loop  for /f  %%x in ( 'DIR /A-D /B /OD /T:C "%%b\*.bak" ') do ( set bakFile="%%x" set BakTime="%%~tx") where %%b is hodling upto that file directory path.

Comment: your set syntax is not correct, batch command delimiter is `&`. also because of variable expansion bakFile and bakTime will be difficult to use the easier is to use a "function" call, updating